# Objects don't really seem to increase speed when falling due to gravity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

Currently I'm working on a project which relies heavily on the physics within Unity 5. For some reason, it seems like the gravity is broken or at least not working naturally. Objects do slow down when they fly up, but they don't really seem to increase speed when falling.

What could be the cause of this? Is it Unity 5, the object, our project settings or is this actually normal behavior?

A video displaying the gravity behavior of the cubes we are using right now: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhxbcwx1ug3iad8/Unity%202015-02-19%2013-41-11-64.avi?dl=0

The properties of the gameobject:

[image]

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com will probably help you better with unity :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll ask it there then.

Comment: Are you checking the rigidbody.velocity to realize if its really being modified or not?

Comment: Well checking the video i can say that the velocity it's being modified, because the blocks fall down. You should probably increase the gravity power in order to increase that velocity. But i'm pretty sure that it's working properly

Comment: I debugged it and it's indeed changing the velocity.
The gravity is already -9.81 so it would be weird that it doesn't behave normally. Maybe it has to do with the Mass in the Rigidbody. Is that in kilos, grams or something else?
Edit. The mass is an arbitrary unit.

Comment: You don't have simple little blocks. You seem to have a "crate" of 1m^3 that you made "only" 40 kilos in weight. Going for some more natural scales should probably see you obtain a more expected behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to notice more the change of velocity, but you could play with the drag value to achieve that

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine.

Those blocks are one meter high, over half the height of a person.

It's all about scale, in order to see realistic results, you have to have realistic scales (if you're going to use realistic gravity values).

What you'll want to do is make a thin "human capsule", about 1.6-1.8 units high, to gauge scale better.

Further analysis:
The stack appears to be 7 high, so that's 7 meters. Those forces you are applying are absolutely huge. The top blocks are being shot up off screen, I am estimating the top of the screen right above the stack to be 5*7 meters high (I got that by duplicating the stack in paint, 5 times until it reached the top of the screen). That's 35 meters high. I don't know if you realise how high that is, but it is very high for a physical object to be launched from a single impulse.

Mass will not affect the rate at which your objects fall to the ground, gravity pulls all objects regardless of mass at the same rate. (*may not be physically accurate, I am not a physicist, but at the scales we're dealing with it's pretty much is the case) Mass is used to resolve contact reaction (i.e. an object with low mass will not move an object with high mass, instead the low mass object will bounce off it.)